# C# how to Deploying  a packed exe with MS clickonce

Tags: c#, clickonce, publish

i am devoloping a C# windows app and i deploying my app with MS Clickonce . 
but i have a problem .
iam using a dongle for this app and i am packing my *.exe .
first step ; publish the project and then i am packing the published exe. after than add file ext. name , like this *.exe.deploy

but ; 
so , dont work this exe .

have you any solution about this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're modifying any of the published files after publish, you'll have to update your .manifest and .application files. Use mageui.exe (location is in bin folder of Windows SDK you have) to edit those files and remember to sign/save when finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to provide a copy of the app, why don't you just build it and then copy the \bin\Release folder to the external drive?

ClickOnce is really meant to deploy an application from a webserver or network share adn give you the ability to publish incremental changes.

If you want to deploy something using ClickOnce from a USB stick, you have to publish the application to a folder, then copy the package over to the usb drive and have the user run setup.exe.

If you do that, you will want to go to the Manifests tab under the Options dialog and check "exclude deployment provider URL". Then when the user installs, it will set the installation URL as the file path to the files on the usb stick. He will have to install updates the same way.